# Combine output into a single table

Tags: powershell

I'm using [this code](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-the-list-of-all-VMs-in-00d6fd89) which I have modified to remove some items that I don't need and I am trying to combine the output into a single table.  I have gotten this far:

```
$SCVMs | ForEach-Object {
  $VMName = Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name | Select -Expand Name
  $ReportData = $ReportData + (Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name |
    Get-SCVirtualHardDisk |
    Select @{Label="VM Name";Expression={$VMName}},
           @{Label="VHD Name";Expression={$_.Name}},
           @{Label="VHD Location";Expression={$_.Location}},
           @{Label="Max Disk Size (GB)";Expression={($_.MaximumSize/1GB)}},
           @{Label="Disk Space Used (GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}},
           @{Label="Disk Space Used (%)";Expression={[math]::Round((($_.Size/1GB)/($_.MaximumSize/1GB))*100)}},
           @{Label="Free Disk Space (GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f (($_.MaximumSize/1GB) - ($_.Size/1GB))}} |
    ConvertTo-Html -as Table -Fragment)
}
```

The report displays the hard drives for a particular VM in the same table but it creates a separate table for each VM.  I would like to generate a single table for all the VMs with a separate row for each hard drive in the VM.

I believe the trick lies in how I select the objects and pipe them along but I'm just not experienced enough to see how to do it.

I don't need the report in HTML, CSV would be fine.

Comment: It looks to me like you've got the gist of it. WHat are you missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pipe each object into `ConvertTo-Html`, so you get a table fragment for each object. Instead of doing that (and appending in a loop on top of that) put `ConvertTo-Html` *outside* the `ForEach-Object` loop.

Change this:

```
$SCVMs | ForEach-Object {
  $VMName = ...
  $ReportData = $ReportData + (Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name |
    Get-SCVirtualHardDisk |
    Select ... |
    ConvertTo-Html -as Table -Fragment)
}
```

into this:

```
$ReportData = $SCVMs | ForEach-Object {
  $VMName = ...
  Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name |
    Get-SCVirtualHardDisk |
    Select ...
} | ConvertTo-Html -as Table -Fragment
```

or this (if you need to append to `$ReportData`):

```
$ReportData += $SCVMs | ForEach-Object {
  $VMName = ...
  Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name |
    Get-SCVirtualHardDisk |
    Select ...
} | ConvertTo-Html -as Table -Fragment
```

To switch to CSV output you just replace `ConvertTo-Html` with `ConvertTo-Csv`  or `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the intermediate variables and remove the ConvertTo-Html from inside your loop. Better still export direct to CSV. Something like this:

```
$SCVMs | ForEach-Object {
$VMName = Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name | Select -Expand Name
$ReportData = $ReportData + (Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name | Get-SCVirtualHardDisk | Select `
    @{Label="VM Name";Expression={$VMName}}, `
    @{Label="VHD Name";Expression={$_.Name}}, `
    @{Label="VHD Location";Expression={$_.Location}}, `
    @{Label="Max Disk Size (GB)";Expression={($_.MaximumSize/1GB)}}, `
    @{Label="Disk Space Used (GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}}, `
    @{Label="Disk Space Used (%)";Expression={[math]::Round((($_.Size/1GB)/($_.MaximumSize/1GB))*100)}}, ` 
    @{Label="Free Disk Space (GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f (($_.MaximumSize/1GB) - ($_.Size/1GB))}} | ConvertTo-HTML -as Table -Fragment) }
```